# Installing Debian 10: Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware

Tags: debian-installer

So I downloaded `firmware.zip` from
http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/stable/current/

And extracted it and copied all of the `.deb` files to the root *and* to `/lib/firmware` (just in case -- the page https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware is rather unclear) a FAT32 formatted USB flash drive but this did not work.

I guess that's not how to do it? (Are there some instructions somewhere?)

Comment: No because we're not trying to install a `.deb` file; we're trying to get the Debian installer to use `firmware.zip` from a USB drive. There is no terminal or `dpkg` or `apt-get` in the installer.

Comment: Like this: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=146221

I've got `firmware.gz` and a USB flash drive but the installer isn't having any of it.

Please stop guessing; I can do that unaided.

Comment: What's also quite peeving is that I'm using `firmware-10.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso` so I was expecting all this shit to be in there already.